# Javascript. How to get the link on page and redirect it?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good afternoon.
The site has a link element with `http://word.site.com/disfhjsdfl`
It should be using JS to find this link and perform a redirect to it. It is interested in the option to redirect. 
I tried something like this, but it did not work.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var links = document.querySelector ( 'a [href * = "word"]').href;
    window.location.replace ( "links");
    break
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, need to get `href` of the element.

```js
var links = document.querySelector('a[href*="word"]').href;
window.location.replace(links); //As link is varible use it directly
```

Comment: Satpal Thank you! Tell me one more. On site synthcafe.ru on the left there are 3 ad units. Each block have link - h ttp://blablabla.bla.xyz/asdasd . I try to execute this script with ".xyz". But when a redirect script tries to follow the link, but returns back to the front page. And the result is cyclical.

Comment: @AndrewFoxis, Sorry mate I am not gona visit that site

Answer (score 1):

**Try**

```
window.onload = function () {
var links = document.querySelector('a[href*="word"]').href;
    window.location.href = links;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Tell me one more. On site synthcafe.ru on the left there are 3 ad units. Each block have link - h ttp://blablabla.bla.xyz/asdasd . I try to execute this script with ".xyz". But when a redirect script tries to follow the link, but returns back to the front page. And the result is cyclical.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your html may look like `<a href="http://word.site.com/disfhjsdfl"></a>` instead make it like `<a class="link" href="http://word.site.com/disfhjsdfl"></a>`

And your js will be

```
var links = $(".link").attr('href');
window.location.replace ( "links");
```

You can also achieve the above just by editing a line

```
var links = document.querySelector('a[href*="word"]').href;
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you can help me... On site synthcafe.ru on the left there are 3 ad units. Each block have link - h ttp://blablabla.bla.xyz/asdasd . I try to execute this script with ".xyz". But when a redirect script tries to follow the link, but returns back to the front page. And the result is cyclical.

Comment: Ya i went through the site, but i thing the script will be same for the links provided in the block and the page is redirecting to previous page (Home page ) just check with the script.

Comment: So it is impossible to go to these units through JS?

Comment: Nothing is impossible  If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link on window load, use location.href instead of location.replace. lets see the result

Comment: Like this? Show me an example please. I am newbie JS :( `<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var links = document.querySelector('a[href*=".xyz"]').href;
    window.location.href = links;
}
</script>`

Comment: Is that giving the same result? What u want to achieve? r u running the this script all over ur project? and can u tell what link is there in href tag

Comment: I want to redirect to one link of this adv block on synthcafe.ru. I used the code right now. Visit the site synthcafe.ru and see the result. It turns cyclicity

Comment: Trying to go to an advertising link but returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136729/discussion-between-rahul-patel-and-andrew-foxis).

Comment: I'a in chat,friend!